# In-class initialization of vector with size

Tags: c++, in-class-initialization, braced-init-list

```
struct Uct
{
    std::vector<int> vec{10};
};
```

The code above creates vector that contains single element with value 10. But I need to initialize the vector with size 10 instead. Just like this:

```
std::vector<int> vec(10);
```

How can I do this with in-class initialization?

Comment: `std::vector<int> vec = std::vector<int>(10);`

Comment: @Evg, does this invoke unnecessary move constructor?

Comment: Starting from C++17, it doesn't due to a mandatory copy/move elision.

Comment: you can use `Uct` constructor to define the size of `vector`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are 2 aswers:

```
std::vector<int> vec = std::vector<int>(10);
```

as said in the comments and:

```
std::vector<int> vec{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

this is less preferable since it's less readable and harder to adjust later on, but I think it's faster (before c++17) because it doesn't invoke a move constructor as said in the comments.

That being said `Uct(): vec(10){};` is also a perfectly viable option with the same properties(I think).

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly

std::vector vec(10,0) to get a 10 elements vector with all elements equal 0.